# should i use throttle or cookie and ip for access limit to login with sms

Tags: laravel, throttling, rate-limiting

I have register/login with SMS on my website. I want to limit number of tries by a user for register or login attempts. They should be able to try 20 time per day for registering or login to website.

What is the best way to impelement this? I have tried using

- laravel throttle middleware
- cookie and ip address of user

to count number of tries. 
which one should i stick to? or there is better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The throttle middleware was built exactly for this, so I would stick with that. The 20-times per day limit could be counted on the User model. You would need to schedule a cron job to reset it to 0 after 24h, though. For more info on rate-limiting, see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#rate-limiting).

Comment: thanks for your answer. So i can limit tries just with Throttle? and using throttle on routes.right?

Comment: Exactly.. I added a link the the rate-limitting docs. You could use throttle to enforce 24sms/day, but that would allow for 24 consecutive login attempts. I would throttle that to one per minute using throttle and write my own middleware to check the user model if 24/day has been reached.

Comment: I added the throttle to login and register routes like this(for test): Route::middleware('throttle:3,1')->group(); 3 times per minute. when it reached 3 times per minute it returned error page code 429 which i customized. I don't think i need another middleware. right?

Comment: and should i use google captcha for login and register?

Comment: A malicious person could figure out they can get you to send a text via SMS 3 times per minute. That's 120 texts per hour. Depending on your rates that can easily amount to $150 per day. I guess I would rather set it to `throttle:1,10` to allow for one text per 10 minutes.

Comment: I wouldn't use captchas until your actually hit problems. If you do, you can still go with honeypots like this: https://freek.dev/1240-preventing-spam-submitted-through-forms

Comment: the `thottle:3,1` was an example. I will make it 10 time per day. So i think the throttle middleware is enough. thank you very much.